# When i use substring, start point is 1, not zero (0)

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I USE MYSQL, not SQL I have this table and i want to select that table with without "M" This is the table i create

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id VARCHAR(10)
);  
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('M1');  
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('M2');
.... 
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('M128');  
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('M129');
```

i want the code select is like this:

```
Select Substring(id,1) from test
```

The result is from "M1" -> "M129"
But when the code like this:

```
Select Substring(id,2) from test
```

The result is from 1 -> 129
so the start point is 1, not 0
But when i read in W3school or some web, it said start point is 0.
Can Somone tell me why?

Comment: Perhaps this was downvoted because it is not well phrased as a question. However this is the first result in google for "mysql substr start position zero", with "zero" spelled out, and gives me exactly what I need, a confirmation that I am not crazy and indeed we start at one, not zero. So thanks for asking!

Comment: A similar question is https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125950/why-do-string-functions-on-sql-based-database-servers-start-at-position-1-instea, but it was closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure what you saw, but the [W3Schools docs for MySql](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp) shows this:

> **Note**
>   The first position in string is 1

[MySql Official](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) looks like this:

> the position of the first character in the string from which the substring is to be extracted is reckoned as 1.

Here are some others:

**[SQL Server Official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)**

> *start*
>   Is an integer or bigint expression that specifies where the returned characters start. (The numbering is 1 based, meaning that the first character in the expression is 1).

**[SQL Server W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp)**

> *start_pos*         Required. The position to start extraction from. The first position in string is 1

**[Oracle Official](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2101.htm#OLADM679)**

> When position is 0 (zero), then it is treated as 1.

And **NONE** of these match the [ansi standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), which is weird, requiring extra `FROM` and `FOR` keywords rather than simple "normal" function semantics.

```
<character substring function> ::=
    SUBSTRING <left paren> <character value expression> FROM <start position>
    [ FOR <string length> ] <right paren>
```

Postgresql is the only database I know having any support for that syntax.

Comment: Maybe because i don't read carefully. I'm not good at English, so maybe i mistake somewhere

Comment: Fwiw, the quoted text is no longer present in the current version on w3schools (I tried find-in-page).

Answer (score 0):

W3schools claims 1 when I look at it:

[image]

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substring.asp

Comment: Maybe because i don't read carefully. I'm not good at English, so maybe i mistake somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Substring syntaxes for mysql are

```
SUBSTR(string,position)
SUBSTR(string,position,length)
```

This is true for mysql that substring start work from position 1(w3school is correct).Now this is matter of your point of view.
How are you thinking about this "position" value in substring.

the number in POSITION work like

according to your first query

```
Select Substring(id,1) from test
```

it means START from POSITION 1

(N.B: Remember this POSITION VALUE not means erase or (remove) from position 1.It means Selected from start position 1)

so the result is M1,M2,M128,M129

according to your second query

```
Select Substring(id,2) from test
```

This Position 2 means "Start from 1. erase id value from position 1 to till position 2(Remember till 2 not with 2)"

For what the result is 1,2,128,129(just removed position 1 value)

Final example is

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('Engineer',5);
```

So it will start from position 1 "E" erase character till position 5 means "N"(not erased value of position 5)

So the result is 'neer'

Comment: Maybe because i don't read carefully. I'm not good at English, so maybe i mistake somewhere